# Simple WampServer tutorial is not working

Tags: php, wampserver

I'm trying to run a simple tutorial with  wampserver 2  ... as a simple test i made a new folder named test under the folder "www" and i turned wampserver online. In the folder test i have "test.php" contains a simple script .
I went to localhost and i selected the folder from the section "your projects" but all the time the server redirect me to this url test/ with the message "the webpage is not avilable"
I'm missing something ?
test.php :

```
 <? php
echo "hello";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this: [Project Links do not work on Wamp Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server)

The user has the same issue it seems to me from reading your post.

Also, try removing the spacing between

```
<?php
echo 'hello world';
?>
```